# Trying to fix this text so that it doesn't go to one letter at a time

Tags: html, css, text, cell

Here is a picture of what these text blocks currently do when the screen gets really small:
[image]

I would like to fix it with so that the words stay together as the screen gets smaller, or that maybe even the image gets smaller?  I have tried using the font size with vw, but it still splits the words up letter by letter.

Here is the current html for it:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div class="w3-cell-row w3-center">
  <span class="w3-cell" style="width:100px">
    <img class="w3-section w3-margin-left" width="96px" height="96px" src="/CustomSpace/EndUserHome/Icons/MSConfigManage-02-WF_96px.svg">
  </span>
  <div class="w3-cell w3-xlarge w3-text-red">
    <div class="text-styling-bold" style="overflow-wrap: anywhere">Help, I Need Something</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Surprise surprise. w3schools ["bootstrap replacement"](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/default.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

learn more about `responsive web` and `flex-box`

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="container">
  <img class="w3-section w3-margin-left" width="96px" height="96px" src="/CustomSpace/EndUserHome/Icons/MSConfigManage-02-WF_96px.svg">
  <div class="w3-xlarge w3-text-red">
    <div class="text-styling-bold" style="overflow-wrap: anywhere">Help, I Need Something</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

W3.css is not a professional library, take a look at [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) and [tailwind.css](https://tailwindcss.com/)

Comment: I will look into all of that, thank you so much!

Comment: you're welcome, if my solution solved your issue, mark it as `accepted` so other user's know this is the solution